# getting 64 bit integer in python

Tags: python, integer, bit

So I am thinking of writing a bitboard in python or lisp. But I don't know how to ensure I would get a 64 bit integer in python. I have been reading documentation and found that mpz library returns a unsigned 32 bit integer. Is this true? If not what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "a bitboard"? How many bits do you really need? What's special about 64-bit integers that would help you solve your problem? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to do bit-twiddling, Python is a very poor choice as the operations will not be compiled into a small number of CPU arithmetic instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options using [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/). Here is one example using gmpy:

```
>>> from gmpy import mpz
>>> a=mpz(7)
>>> bin(a)
'0b111'
>>> a=a.setbit(48)
>>> bin(a)
'0b1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111'
>>>
```

gmpy2 is the development version of gmpy and includes a new type called xmpz that allows more direct access to the bits.

```
>>> from gmpy2 import xmpz
>>> a=xmpz(7)
>>> bin(a)
'0b111'
>>> a[48]=1
>>> bin(a)
'0b1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111'
>>>
```

There are other solutions such as [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) you might want to look at.

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy and gmpy2.

Comment: Are bitarrays as fast as mpz?

Comment: I haven't compared the performance with bitarray. In the example above, xmpz bit access is about twice as fast as mpz.

Comment: With `gmpy` after `a=a.setbit(48)` the value of a changes to `mpz(281474976710663)` because of the first bit. I'm not sure why is this the case, is this the meant behaviour? If I manually change the beginning of the '0b0' instead of '0b1' (as it weas introduced by the conversion to 48 bits) it works fine. Is there a better way around it?

Answer (score 37):

Python 2 has two integer types: `int`, which is a signed integer whose size equals your machine's word size (but is always at least 32 bits), and `long`, which is unlimited in size.

Python 3 has only one integer type, which is called `int` but is equivalent to a Python 2 `long`.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Basically I need 64 bits to represent a chess board. I have been reading the source code of some programs and they use mpz. But unfortunately it's not documented very well. If I want to store an integer in 64 bits what should I do? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Mark You are looking at some rather outdated code. From [PEP 4](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0004/): The mpz module has been documented as obsolete since Python 2.2. Removed from the library reference in Python 2.4.

Comment: @JanneKarila: I think MPZ was reimplemented in a module called gmpy. Most programs I am reading seems to include mpz from gmpy.

Comment: @Mark OK, then see [gmpy docs](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/browse/trunk/doc/gmpydoc.txt#242): An mpz object can be transformed into a Python number by passing it as the argument of a call to Python's built-in number types
(int, long, float, complex). For example, use `long(x)`